# Scala method override in Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, overriding

I have a method in Scala with below syntax . I want to override this method in a java sub class. I am not sure what will be the equivalent syntax in Java for this method .

```
def createRecord(rdd: RDD[(String, Array[(String, Int)])])
```

Comment: what is the return type of the method?

Comment: Return type is Unit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the below is the java equivalent of the scala method createRecord.
The reason why Int in scala is converted to an Object in Java is provided [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/11034)

```
 import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD;
 import scala.Tuple2;
 public void createRecord(RDD<Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String, Object>[]>> rdd) {

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use The Java API RDD of spark as well and Integer (a class ) here as:

```
import scala.Tuple2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD

 public void method(JavaRDD<Tuple2<String,Tuple2<String,Integer>[]>> rdd)
  {
      return the equivalent implementation
  }
```